# Codeigniter Model Getting Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 2

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, model

I am parsing currency rates from a rss.xml feed that all works great. I am now trying to insert that data into a database called rates with a table called tblRates. I keep getting this error and do not know why. Here is the function in the model I am using to try to batch insert into the database.

```
function addIQDRates($Data){

    if($this->db->insert_batch('tblRates', $Data, 'Currency'))
    {
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Also here is the foreach statement I am using in my controller to sort the data from the xml file and to insert it into the database. 
$Data = array();

```
$Data = array();
$Count = 0;

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $currencyInfo) {
  $Data[$Count]['Currency'] = trim(str_replace("/USD", "", $currencyInfo->title)); // UNIQUE
  $Data[$Count]['PubDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(trim($currencyInfo->pubDate)));
  $Data['CXRate'] = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", str_replace("1 United States Dollar = ", "", $currencyInfo->description)));
  $Data[$Count]['DateCreated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');                      
  $Count++;         
}

$TotalRows = $this->mycron_model->addIQDRates($Data);
```

Also here is my Create Table statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblRates` (
`RateID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Currency` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`PubDate` datetime NOT NULL,
`CXRate` int(11) NOT NULL,
`DateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`RateID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

all help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, you might have written `$Data['CXRate']` instead of `$Data[$Count]['CXRate']`.

So the loop should like like below:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $currencyInfo) {
   $Data[$Count]['Currency'] = trim(str_replace("/USD", "", $currencyInfo->title)); // UNIQUE
   $Data[$Count]['PubDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(trim($currencyInfo->pubDate)));
   $Data[$Count]['CXRate'] = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9,.]/", "", str_replace("1 United States Dollar = ", "", $currencyInfo->description)));
   $Data[$Count]['DateCreated'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');                      
   $Count++;         
 }
```